# How can I generate sequence in Sql month wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using query and get format like this

```
select CONCAT('D','/',FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM-yy'),'/')
```

D/11-22/

now I add in this format one more thing is sequence which start number of 1,2,3,4... and when month was change then sequence is start from 1, like this example,

```
D/11-22/1
D/11-22/2
D/11-22/3
D/12-22/1
D/12-22/2
```

so how can I use query and get format like this ??

I try above query and getting that format

Comment: Honestly, I would just calculate the `ROW_NUMBER` in the SQL layer, and then have the presentation layer worry about the formatting. Though I am confused by your sample data; `GETDATE()` is unlikely to return different times, let alone dates, within the same query.

Comment: I was `GetDate()`  use for getting month number like 11

Comment: Yes, but as you are using `GETDATE()` the value of the date isn't going to change, so you won't have a row for November and December because they'll all be for the *current* date (and time).

Comment: i want to increment in sequence by getting from first entry of the table and increment with max sequence..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checking your task, follows a query what I think could help you, I'm using partition to group row number by month and year

```
    WITH table1  AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('2022-01-01', 'John Smith'), 
        ('2022-01-02', 'John Smith'), 
        ('2022-01-03', 'John Smith'), 
        ('2022-02-01', 'David Thompson'), 
        ('2022-02-02', 'David Thompson'),
        ('2022-02-02', 'David Thompson'),
        ('2022-02-03', 'Stacey Leigh'),
        ('2022-03-01', 'Stacey Leigh'),
        ('2023-01-01', 'John Smith'), 
        ('2023-01-02', 'John Smith'), 
        ('2023-01-03', 'John Smith'), 
        ('2023-02-01', 'David Thompson'), 
        ('2023-02-02', 'David Thompson'),
        ('2023-02-02', 'David Thompson'),
        ('2023-02-03', 'Stacey Leigh'),
        ('2023-03-01', 'Stacey Leigh')
    
    ) AS _ (MyDate,UserName)
)

select 
    CONCAT('D','/',FORMAT(CAST(myDate as date), 'MM-yy') ,'/', myMonthIndex)  as MyFormat
from 
     (
     select 
        t.*,
        (row_number() over (partition by Month(MyDate), year(MyDate) order by MyDate)) as myMonthIndex
      from 
        table1 as t
     ) t
```

the result

```
    MyFormat
    D/01-22/1
    D/01-22/2
    D/01-22/3
    D/01-23/1
    D/01-23/2
    D/01-23/3
    D/02-22/1
    D/02-22/2
    D/02-22/3
    D/02-22/4
    D/02-23/1
    D/02-23/2
    D/02-23/3
    D/02-23/4
    D/03-22/1
    D/03-23/1
```

Best Regards

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me, Also here requirement is year was change then sequence was start from 1,2,3.. bcz when year change and month is same started then entry is like 
` D/11-22/8`
`D/12-22/1`
`D/12-23/2 ` this is the problem i face in future

Comment: Hi, DDProgrammmer you are right the year also important, I did the update on code, to consider the year too, to reset the counter, take a look when you can.